# Angular md-select in md-dialog

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am using a `md-select` in a `md-dialog`. The drop down content has a scroll bar but I need the window to scroll.

Here is my code:

**Dialog (in `script` element)**:

```
<md-dialog aria-label="Mango (Fruit)">
  <form ng-cloak>
    <md-toolbar>
      <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <h2>Click Select menu and then scroll the page</h2>
        <span flex></span>
        <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="cancel()">
          <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/ic_close_24px.svg" aria-label="Close dialog"></md-icon>
        </md-button>
      </div>
    </md-toolbar>

    <md-dialog-content>
      <div class="md-dialog-content" layout="row" layout-align="center">

        <md-input-container flex="80">
          <label>Selcet your option</label>
          <md-select ng-model="size">
            <md-option value="option 1">option 1</md-option>
            <md-option value="option 2">option 2</md-option>
            <md-option value="option 3">option 3</md-option>
          </md-select>
        </md-input-container>
      </div>
    </md-dialog-content>

    <md-dialog-actions layout="row">
      <md-button href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mango" target="_blank" md-autofocus>
        More on Wikipedia
      </md-button>
      <span flex></span>
      <md-button ng-click="answer('not useful')">
        Not Useful
      </md-button>
      <md-button ng-click="answer('useful')">
        Useful
      </md-button>
    </md-dialog-actions>
  </form>
</md-dialog>
```

The issue is that the content of the `md-select` is moving along with the scrolling. Can anyone suggest me a fix for this issue? I need both the window and `md-select` content to scroll.Thanks in advance.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/zoeychan2013/pen/BLdLgy)

Comment: https://github.com/angular/material/issues/5435

Comment: Can u convert the codepen to a Working plunker.